# Avoid Message Contract in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Hi it might be a duplicate but writing here since i was unable to fix the issue from the posts i have seen so far.

I am having DataContracts in my WCF services and on my client I want to consume my services as DataContract objects only, but when i am creating a Service reference my WCF services generating the message contracts for all the methods.

```
  [ServiceContract]

public interface IUserService
{
    [OperationContract]
     UserVO GetUser(int Id);
}

[DataContract]
public Class UserVO
{
 [DataMember]
 public int Id{get;set;};
}
```

I have un-checked the "Always generate message contracts" and checked reuse types in referenced libraries where entities are available(Data Contract).

My reference.cs is having a message contract like

```
System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="GetUser",      WrapperNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class GetUserRequest {
 }
```

EDIT 1:

my Reference.svcmap has client configuration like this

```
 <ClientOptions>
<GenerateAsynchronousMethods>false</GenerateAsynchronousMethods>
<EnableDataBinding>true</EnableDataBinding>
<ExcludedTypes />
<ImportXmlTypes>false</ImportXmlTypes>
<GenerateInternalTypes>false</GenerateInternalTypes>
<GenerateMessageContracts>false</GenerateMessageContracts>
<NamespaceMappings />
<CollectionMappings>
  <CollectionMapping TypeName="System.Collections.Generic.List`1" Category="List" />
</CollectionMappings>
<GenerateSerializableTypes>true</GenerateSerializableTypes>
<Serializer>Auto</Serializer>
<UseSerializerForFaults>true</UseSerializerForFaults>
<ReferenceAllAssemblies>true</ReferenceAllAssemblies>
<ReferencedAssemblies />
<ReferencedDataContractTypes />
<ServiceContractMappings />
```

EDIT 2:
I am trying to achieve something like below

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IUserService/GetUserDetails", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IUserService/GetUserDetailsResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(UserServiceFaultContract), Action="http://tempuri.org/IUserService/GetUserDetailsUserServiceFaultContractFault", Name="UserServiceFaultContract", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mynamespace")]
    MyEntities.UserVO GetUserDetails(int id);
```

Comment: I don't see a question?

Comment: I want to avoid creation of message contracts in my client

Comment: Still no question. What is the problem???

Comment: I want to use DataContracts on my client instead of message contracts but it is creating message contracts always.

Answer (score 0):

By default, WCF uses the `DataContractSerializer` class to serialize data types.  If your scenario requires the use of the `XmlSerializer`, instead, then you can manually switch to the `XmlSerializer` by applying the `XmlSerializerFormatAttribute` attribute to your service

The following MSDN article describes the process:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901(v=vs.110).aspx

Recommend careful consideration of the security notes before switching serialization classes.

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear , even i want DataContractSerializer Seymour,      please refer to my Edit 2

Answer (score 0):

Then share the assembly with the client! Put the service interface and all the DataContracts in one assembly. Then the client can use the channel channelfactory "pattern" to connect to the WCF service.

Comment: @jack.. I am sharing my datacontracts assembly to the client and configuring the service to use all the referenced assemblies , but it is overwriting my selection and creating MessageContracts and Arraylist , where as i configured it for Use referenced libraries and Collection type as Generic list